# Ionic docker Failed to open the browser

Tags: docker, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm using ionic with docker and when i try to execute the command ionic serve that execute the app on the browser i have this error :

```
root@00209e483f93:/var/www/espaceproold# ionic serve
[INFO] Starting app-scripts server: --port 8100 --p 8100 --livereload-port 35729 --r 35729 --address 0.0.0.0 - Ctrl+C to
       cancel

[13:54:41]  watch started ...
[13:54:41]  build dev started ...
[13:54:41]  clean started ...
[13:54:41]  clean finished in 7 ms
[13:54:41]  copy started ...
[13:54:41]  transpile started ...
[13:54:45]  transpile finished in 3.50 s
[13:54:45]  preprocess started ...
[13:54:45]  deeplinks started ...
[13:54:45]  deeplinks finished in 47 ms
[13:54:45]  preprocess finished in 49 ms
[13:54:45]  webpack started ...
[13:54:45]  copy finished in 4.10 s
[13:54:55]  webpack finished in 10.18 s
[13:54:55]  sass started ...
[13:54:57]  sass finished in 1.55 s
[13:54:57]  postprocess started ...
[13:54:57]  postprocess finished in 18 ms
[13:54:57]  lint started ...
[13:54:57]  build dev finished in 15.37 s
[13:54:57]  watch ready in 15.48 s
[13:54:57]  dev server running: http://localhost:8100/

[13:54:57]  Failed to open the browser: Command failed: xdg-open "http://localhost:8100" /bin/sh: 1: xdg-open: not found
[13:55:00]  lint finished in 3.41 s
```

docker file :

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER ""
# Install apt packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git lib32stdc++6 lib32z1 curl openjdk-8-jdk-headless sendemail libio-socket-ssl-perl libnet-ssleay-perl && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
# Install android SDK, tools and platforms 
RUN cd /opt && curl https://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz -o android-sdk.tgz && tar xzf android-sdk.tgz && rm android-sdk.tgz
ENV ANDROID_HOME /opt/android-sdk-linux
RUN echo 'y' | /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android update sdk -u -a -t platform-tools,build-tools-23.0.3,android-23,extra-android-support,extra-google-m2repository,extra-android-m2repository
# accept the license agreements of the SDK components
RUN export ANDROID_LICENSES="$ANDROID_HOME/licenses" && \
    [ -d $ANDROID_LICENSES ] || mkdir $ANDROID_LICENSES && \
    [ -f $ANDROID_LICENSES/android-sdk-license ] || echo 8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55 > $ANDROID_LICENSES/android-sdk-license && \
    [ -f $ANDROID_LICENSES/android-sdk-preview-license ] || echo 84831b9409646a918e30573bab4c9c91346d8abd > $ANDROID_LICENSES/android-sdk-preview-license && \
    [ -f $ANDROID_LICENSES/intel-android-extra-license ] || echo d975f751698a77b662f1254ddbeed3901e976f5a > $ANDROID_LICENSES/intel-android-extra-license && \
    unset ANDROID_LICENSES
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y -q \
    nodejs \
    gradle \
    && apt-get -y autoclean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
# Install npm packages
RUN npm install -g ionic
RUN npm install -g cordova
# Setup environment
ENV ANDROID_HOME /opt/android-sdk-linux
ENV PATH ${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools
EXPOSE 8100 35729
```

Is there anything wrong with my dockerfile? Or what is the issue?
thanks in advance !

Comment: Your ionic server tries to open a browser on a docker container, where there is no browser. Is there any `production` mode on ionic that would skip this opening?

Comment: thank you for your response but i'm wondering how can i install google chrome on the container ?? or how i can run my app localy ???

Comment: you don't want to do that, just `ionic serve --nobrowser` in container and check you can reach the server from another machine with this machine's browser.

Comment: i have docker localy and when i want to access to the container with http://localhost:8100 on the browser of my windows i have nothing

Comment: True, you then have to get ip of your docker container to be able to set it in your browser: `docker ps` then get id of container, then `docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_id`. Finally use that ip to browse your ionic app (http://192.168.0.2:8100 for instance). Or if you want to keep localhost, run the container with `--publish`. For instance `docker run -p127.0.0.1:8100:8100 myionicimage:tag`.

Comment: what do you mean about myionicimage ????

Comment: myionicimage is the name you have to replace with the one of your docker image built from dockerfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [ionic documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/serve/), you should run ionic with this option:

```
--nobrowser,-b    |    Disable launching a browser
```

This will prevent `ionic serve` to try launching a browser to display your site.

Moreover, you certainly don't want in production to enable `live-reload`. you can use `--nolivereload` then. It's ok to keep `live-reload` if you are on a development mode.

Comment: thank you my friend for your help !!!!!
The problem whas that i have to open a route between the private network and the host OS by running the following command from an elevated command prompt: 
route add 172.17.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0 10.0.75.2 -p